# set variable in Worksheets()

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get a string from a text box, make a sheet with the string name and then set variable `WS` and use it to put the name of the sheet in the first cell.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim nazov As String

nazov = Me.NazovReceptu
Sheets.Add.Name = nazov

Set WS = Worksheets(nazov)

With WS
.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = nazov
End With

'find first empty row in database
lRow = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
...
```

I managed to get the string from the text box, make a sheet with the string as the name, but the rest doesn't work. I know that `Set WS = Worksheets("nazov")` is bad. I want to make more sheets with different names and use variable WS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this - define WS when you're adding the sheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nazov As String
Dim lRow as integer

nazov = "testsheet"
lRow = 1    
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = nazov
ws.Cells(lrow, 1).Value = nazov

[...]
```

Comment: thaks, its ok until "ws.Cells(lrow, 1).Value = nazov" than it failed. it display me "application-defined or object defined-error".

Comment: That suggests that nazov has no value. I copied your code from above which gave nazov the value of Me.NazovReceptu. To test it, try replacing the `nazov = Me.NazovReceptu` line with `nazov = "testsheet"` - that will create a sheet called testsheet.

Comment: i tried it. it made me sheet named "testsheet", but it failed again on this line.

Comment: OK - other thing to check is that you have a value for lRow - I didn't define it in my code, I've edited it so you can test with lRow set to 1 and nazov set to TestSheet

Comment: so, now it works.problem was, that i didnt defined value of lRow (it was primary = 0) thank you for help.